# Copy PHP application from Jenkins to /var/www/html

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, jenkins, centos

I have installed Jenkins and Apache to one instance of CentOS in aws. I have connected Jenkins with github but I am not able to access the application through url as it shows the following error.

> You should add your website content to the directory /var/www/html/.

I need to copy files from jenkins directory to the mentioned one can you please help me how to copy app so that I can use it on browser.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide more details about the way you are using Jenkins?

Comment: I have installed jenkins on docker container using aws ec2 containers then I tried to fetch app from repo and started to build in jenkins.

I have also installed apache2 and maria db

Comment: Can you provide more detailed informations how your Jenkins job is configured (screenshots at least)? If you are running all on one machine you can just copy build artifacts from Jenkins workspace to `/var/www/html/` using [`cp`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) or sth like that.